# PHP Ecommerce Declaring Variables

Tags: php, html, variables, e-commerce

I have 10 packages and 2 base pages for a check out page. Would I be able to declare variables in an if & elseif statement's to then echo them if they are true?

Example:

```
<?php 
$package = $_POST['pack'];

if($pack == 1) {
   $value = "item-1";
   $value-2 = "gross-1";
} elseif ($pack == 2) {
   $value = "item-2";
   $value-2 = "gross-2";
} elseif($pack == 3) {
   $value = "item-3";
   $value-2 = "gross-3"; {
} elseif($pack == 4) {
   $value = "item-4";
   $value-2 = "gross-4";
} elseif($pack == 5) {
   $value = "item-5";
   $value-2 = "gross-5";
} else {
$value = 0;
$value-2 = 0;
}
<form action="PayPal">
   <input value='<?php echo $value; ?>' name="whatever">
   <input value='<?php echo $value; ?>' name="whatever-2">
</form>
```

So basically I need variable's in accordance of a true statement, so they can be echoed in the pages to display values.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

```
$package = $_POST['pack'];

if($pack == 1) {
   $value = "item-1";
   $value_2 = "gross-1";
} else if ($pack == 2) {
   $value = "item-2";
   $value_2 = "gross-2";
} else if($pack == 3) {
   $value = "item-3";
   $value_2 = "gross-3"; {
} else if($pack == 4) {
   $value = "item-4";
   $value_2 = "gross-4";
} else if($pack == 5) {
   $value = "item-5";
   $value_2 = "gross-5";
} else {
$value = 0;
$value_2 = 0;
}
<form action="PayPal">
   <input value='<?php echo $value; ?>' name="whatever">
   <input value='<?php echo $value_2; ?>' name="whatever_2">
</form>
```